# How to simplify code uses ActiveCell & Formulas & Autofit Columns?

Tags: excel, vba

Have data in "Risk Partner Data" sheet and calculations to appear in "Calc Data"

How would I simplify the below code?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=CONCATENATE(RPdata[@[Parish Code]]&"", ""&RPdata[@Parish])"
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A520"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A2:A520").Select
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RPdata[@[Building ID 1]]"
Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B505")
Range("B2:B505").Select
Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RPdata[@[Basis of Cover]]=""Demolition"",RPdata[@Demolition],IF(RPdata[@[Basis of Cover]]=""Replacement"",SUM(RPdata[@[Replacement Value]:[Demolition]]), IF(RPdata[@[Basis of Cover]]=""Indemnity"",SUM(RPdata[@[Indemnity Value]:[Indemnity Inflation Value]],RPdata[@[Agreed Value]]))))"
    Range("F3").Select
    Sheets("Calc Data").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F505")
    Range("F2:F505").Select
```

My Objective: Should data change in the "Risk Partner Data" it be automatically picked up in the "Calc Data" sheet. Fill for all active cells .End(1xUp)?

Would appreciate assistance.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Welcome, @RoakuSezoire! At just a glance, one thing you can do is for every line that has `Range("B2").Select` (or any other range that isn't `B2`), delete that line and replace the next `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` with `Range("B2").FormulaR1C1`. This is just an example. Basically, any place that has `.Select` can be removed and the `Range` reference can replace the immediately following `ActiveCell`. No need to select it first.

Comment: Thanks Totsie! Its looking much better with your suggestion. Is there a way to make the below account for a change in range? 
`Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A520"), Type:=xlFillDefaul`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much context, but this might get you started.

You can eliminate all of the selection switching and autofill stuff:

```
Range("A2:A520").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(RPdata[@[Parish Code]]&"", ""&RPdata[@Parish])"

Range("B2:B505").Formula = "=RPdata[@[Building ID 1]]"

Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Range("F2:F505").Formula = _
"=IF(RPdata[@[Basis of Cover]]=""Demolition"",RPdata[@Demolition],IF(RPdata[@[Basis of Cover]]=""Replacement"",SUM(RPdata[@[Replacement Value]:[Demolition]]), IF(RPdata[@[Basis of Cover]]=""Indemnity"",SUM(RPdata[@[Indemnity Value]:[Indemnity Inflation Value]],RPdata[@[Agreed Value]]))))"
```

Comment: Hi Valon, thank you for your response! What if my range changes? How can I account for when I need the data to autofill to the correct range in the sheet based on the data of the other sheet? How do I use the .end(1xUp) code? I think that one would make it fill until the end of the active cells?

Comment: It looks like your data is in a table, so you could change the reference to a listcolumn, which is dynamic. I just don't have enough info from your post. For example, you could use `thisworkbook.sheets("[sheet name]").listobject("[Table Name]").listcolumns("[column name]").databodyrange.formula = "[Formula]"`

Comment: What is the name of the sheet, table, and columns that these formulas are in?

Comment: Name of sheet with table "Risk Partner Data", table name "RPData", columns are named in my original code. The sheet where the data is to be calculated in is "Calc Data" and it has no table just A - J calculation results based on my formula which uses the data stored in the table "RP data".